# Unexpected String in a Json file by removing the firebase plugin

Tags: android, firebase, cordova, cordova-plugins, apache-cordova

When I try to remove the apache cordova plugin "cordova-plugin-firebase", I get the error "Unexpected string in JSON at position 1296" but the console don't show a file or something which help me to understand the error. 
Do someone have an idea?

I remove every platform and that don't help to remove this error.

The comand line:

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-firebase
```

The result:

```
Removing "cordova-plugin-firebase"
Unexpected string in JSON at position 1296
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "AppName",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "cordova-plugin-firebase": "^2.0.5",
    "phonegap-plugin-multidex": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "cordova": {
    "platforms": [],
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-dialogs": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "es6-promise-plugin": {},
      "cordova-plugin-deeplinks": {},
      "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {},
      "cordova-plugin-extension": {},
      "cordova-admobsdk": {},
      "cordova-plugin-admobpro": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
      "phonegap-plugin-multidex": {},
      "phonegap-plugin-push": {},
      "cordova-plugin-firebase": {}
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.2.2",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "~3.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-dialogs": "~2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "~2.0.2",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "~4.2.2",
    "cordova-plugin-deeplinks": "~1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "~5.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-extension": "~1.5.4",
    "cordova-admobsdk": "~7.35.0",
    "cordova-plugin-admobpro": "~2.35.3",
    "phonegap-plugin-push": "~2.2.3",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "~2.4.1",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase": "~2.0.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you change anything in your package.json?

Comment: Not really, I remove a line but after update the android platform the line is back. I could update my post and add the package.json

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
rm package-lock.json
rm node_modules
npm install
```

and then your command

`cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-firebase`

Comment: Thanks for the idea but it don't help. I still get the error result

Comment: Very strange.... there's a malformed .json somewhere....
Your package.json seems valid. A usual problem is an extra comma `,` but that's not the case